# The coproduct on the 2-boxes space of the group-subgroup subfactor planar algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, finite-groups, subfactors, planar-algebras

Let $(H \subset G)$ be an inclusion of finite groups.
Let the subfactor $(\mathcal{R} \rtimes H \subset \mathcal{R} \rtimes G)$ with $\mathcal{R}$ the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factor, and its planar algebra $\mathcal{P}$.

On the $2$-boxes space  of a planar algebra, there is the coproduct $a * b$ (defined for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5656) p4).
For the group-subgroup subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P}$ above, the $2$-boxes space $\mathcal{P}_2 = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{C}e_i$ as an algebra, indexed as the double cosets partition  $G = \coprod_{i \in I} Hg_iH$   (see [Jones-Sunder](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/introduction-subfactors) p141).

**Question 1**: How compute the coproduct on $\mathcal{P}_2$?

*Remark*:  my guess is that $e_i * e_j \sim \sum_{k \in K} e_k$ with $Hg_iHg_jH = \coprod_{k \in K} Hg_kH$.
 Is it true?  How prove that?   [the relation $\sim$ means same support]

I've written a program computing my guess.
*Example*: For $(\mathcal{R} \rtimes S_2 \subset \mathcal{R} \rtimes S_4)$, with $\mathcal{P}_2 =  \bigoplus_{i=1,\dots 7} \mathbb{C}e_i $,
I've found the following coproduct table (up to $\sim$):

$ \begin{array}{c|c}  
* & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 & e_7 \newline   \hline 
  e_1 & e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 & e_7 \newline   \hline 
  e_2 &e_2 & e_1+ e_2 & e_4+ e_5 & e_3+ e_5 & e_3+ e_4 & e_6+ e_7 & e_6 \newline  \hline 
  e_3 & e_3 & e_5+ e_6 & e_1+ e_3 & e_4+ e_7 & e_2+ e_6 & e_2+ e_5 & e_4 \newline  \hline
   e_4 & e_4 & e_4+ e_7 & e_2+ e_5 & e_5+ e_6 & e_2+ e_6 & e_1+ e_3 & e_3 \newline  \hline 
 e_5 & e_5 & e_3+ e_6 & e_2+ e_4 & e_3+ e_6 & e_1+ e_7 & e_2+ e_4 & e_5 \newline   \hline
e_6 &  e_6 & e_3+ e_5 & e_6+ e_7 & e_1+ e_2 & e_3+ e_4 & e_4+ e_5 & e_2 \newline   \hline
 e_7 & e_7 & e_4 & e_6 & e_2 & e_5 & e_3 & e_1  
 \end{array}$

**Question 2**: What's this coproduct for $(\mathcal{R} ^ G \subset \mathcal{R} ^ H)$?
*Example:* for  $(\mathcal{R} ^{S_4} \subset \mathcal{R} ^{S_2})$ with $\mathcal{P}_2 =  \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus M_2(\mathbb{C}) $, what's the coproduct?

Answer (score 1):

[Zhengwei](https://mathoverflow.net/users/57468/zhengwei-liu)'s (email) answer for the *question 1*:

> Your guess is right.   Group subgroup subfactors can be considered as
>   a biprojection cut down of group subfactors.    We can drive its
>   coproduct from the group case.