# Generalization of a theorem of Øystein Ore in group theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattices, subfactors, computational-group-theory

**Theorem** ([Øystein Ore, 1938](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-4/issue-2/Structures-and-group-theory-II/10.1215/S0012-7094-38-00419-3.short)): A finite group $G$ is cyclic iff its lattice of subgroups $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice).
*Proof*: see below.

Let $(H \subset G)$  be an inclusion of finite groups and $\mathcal{L}(H \subset G)$ its lattice of intermediate subgroups.
I would like to generalize the above theorem of Øystein Ore to the inclusions of finite groups, i.e. find an equivalent formulation of the following property $(D)$, in term of "cyclic" notions. $$(D) \ \ \  \ \mathcal{L}(H \subset G) \text{ is distributive } $$   *Definition*: An inclusion of finite groups $(H \subset G)$ is **cyclic** if it checks $(C_0)$.
$$(C_0) \ \ \ \exists g \in G \text{ such that }  \langle H,g \rangle = G$$    *Examples*: The maximal inclusions are cyclic, and $(\{e\} \subset G)$ is cyclic iff $G$  is cyclic.

**Question**:  $(D)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(C_0)$ ?

*Remark*: I've checked that it's true for index $[G:H]<32$ and $\vert G \vert \le 5.10^5$ with [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/).
The converse is false: $(S_2 \subset S_4)$ is a cyclic inclusion with a non-distributive lattice.

---

*Bonus question*: How complete  $(C_0)$ for having an equivalence with $(D)$?

I've tried all the following completions of strictly increasing strongness:

- $(C_1) \ $ $\forall K$, $H \le K \le G$, $\exists g \in G$ such that  $\langle H,g \rangle = K$
- $(C_2) \ $ $\forall K$, $H \le K \le G$, $\exists g \in G$, $\exists n \ge 0$ such that  $\langle H,g \rangle = G$ and $\langle H,g^n \rangle = K$
- $(C_3) \ $ $\exists g \in G$, $\forall K$, $H \le K \le G$, $\exists n \ge 0$ such that $\langle H,g^n \rangle = K$

*Conjecture*: $(D)$ is strictly between $(C_1)$ and $(C_3)$.
I've checked it for index $[G:H] < 32$ and $\vert G \vert \le 10^4$. Moreover $(D)$  is *not orderable* with $(C_2)$.

*Remark*: All these notions and questions can be extended to the [theory of subfactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor) by using the coproduct of minimal projections on the $2$-boxes space (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179179/34538) and [there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179188/34538)).

---

*Remark*: We give here the proof of the stronger version of the theorem, for the l[ocally cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group) (i.e. every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic), because it's more relevant for an attempt of generalization.

**Proof** of the theorem of Øystein Ore (coming from [this book](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Subgroup_Lattices_of_Groups.html?id=EuVadOnix5MC&redir_esc=y) p12-13):

Suppose first that $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is distributive and let $a,b \in G$. We have to show that $\langle a,b \rangle$ is cyclic. Because $\langle a \rangle \wedge \langle b \rangle$ is centralized by $a$ and $b$, $(\langle a \rangle \wedge \langle b \rangle) \leq Z(\langle a,b \rangle)$.  Also,$\langle ab \rangle \vee \langle a \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle = \langle ab \rangle \vee \langle b \rangle$, and then by distributivity $$ \langle ab \rangle \vee (\langle a \rangle \wedge \langle b \rangle) = (\langle ab \rangle \vee \langle a \rangle) \wedge (\langle ab \rangle \vee \langle b \rangle) = \langle a,b \rangle $$
So, $\langle a,b \rangle / (\langle a \rangle \wedge \langle b \rangle) \simeq \langle ab \rangle /(\langle ab \rangle \wedge (\langle a \rangle \wedge \langle b \rangle) )$ is cyclic, and then $\langle a,b \rangle$ is abelian, as cyclic extension of a central subgroup. By the structure of finitely generated abelian groups, there are $c,d \in G$ such that $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c \rangle \times \langle d \rangle$. As we've already shown, $\langle c,d \rangle / \langle c \rangle \wedge \langle d \rangle$ is cyclic. Because $\langle c \rangle \wedge \langle d \rangle = 1$, $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c,d \rangle $ is cyclic.

Now suppose that $G$ is locally  cyclic and let $A,B,C \in \mathcal{L}(G)$. Because $G$ is abelian,
we just need to verify that $A(B \wedge C) = AB \wedge AC$.  Clearly, $A(B \wedge C) \leq AB \wedge AC$.
Let $x \in AB \wedge AC$, then $x=ab=a'c$ with $a,a' \in A$, $b \in B$ and $c \in C$.
Because $G$ is locally cyclic, $\exists g \in G$ such that $\langle a,a',b,c \rangle = \langle g \rangle$. Next, $ab=a'c$ implies that  $\langle g \rangle = (A \wedge \langle g \rangle)(B \wedge \langle g \rangle)=(A \wedge \langle g \rangle)(C \wedge \langle g \rangle)$. If one of the three subgroups $A \wedge \langle g \rangle$, $B \wedge \langle g \rangle$, $C \wedge \langle g \rangle$ is trivial, then $x=b=c \in B \wedge C$ or $x \in A$. In each case, $x \in A(B \wedge C)$.
So suppose that all these subgroups are non-trivial and let $n,r,s$ the respective indices  of $A \wedge \langle g \rangle$, $B \wedge \langle g \rangle$, $C \wedge \langle g \rangle$ in $\langle g \rangle$. So $(n,r) = 1 = (n,s)$, and then $(n,rs) = 1$ and so $\langle g \rangle = \langle g^n \rangle \langle g^{rs} \rangle = (A \wedge \langle g \rangle) (B \wedge C \wedge \langle g \rangle) \leq A(B \wedge C)$.
Again, it follows that $x \in A(B \wedge C)$. So $A(B \wedge C) = AB \wedge AC$ as expected.  $\square$

*Remark*: For a  finite cyclic group $G$, the second part of the proof can be reduced to the facts that $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $ord(G)$, and that [lcm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) and [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) are distributive.

Comment: See the dual version of this post [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/195366/34538).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer of the main question is **yes**. Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup.

*Definition*: The group $G$ is called $H$-cyclic if $\exists g \in G$ such that $\langle H,g \rangle = G$.
Note that: $\langle H,g \rangle = G \Leftrightarrow \langle Hg \rangle = G$.
**Ore's theorem for intervals** (1938): If the interval $[H,G]$ is distributive, then $G$ is $H$-cyclic.
*proof*: see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077490633), Theorem 7 p269.

The following is a new proof.

*Lemma 0*: The top interval of a distributive lattice, is boolean.
*proof*: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212340/34538).
*Lemma 1:* If $H$ is a maximal subgroup then $G$ is $H$-cyclic.
*proof*: immediate.
*Lemma 2:* Let $[K,G]$ be the  top interval of $[H,G]$. If $G$ is $K$-cyclic then it is $H$-cyclic.
*proof*: straightforward.

So the proof of Ore's theorem for intervals reduces to the following Theorem.

*Theorem*: If the interval $[H,G]$ is boolean, then $G$ is $H$-cyclic.
*proof*: Let $M$ be a coatom of $[H,G]$, and $M^{\complement}$ its complement.  By induction on the rank of the lattice (and Lemma 1), we can assume $M$ and $M^{\complement}$  both $H$-cyclic, i.e. there are $a, b \in G$ such that $\langle H,a \rangle = M$ and $\langle H,b \rangle = M^{\complement}$. Let $g=a  b$ then $a=g  b^{-1}$ and $b=a^{-1}g$, so $\langle H,a,g \rangle = \langle H,g,b \rangle = \langle H,a,b \rangle =  M \vee M^{\complement} = G$.
Now, $\langle H,g \rangle =  \langle H,g \rangle \vee H = \langle H,g \rangle \vee (M \wedge M^{\complement})$, but by distributivity $\langle H,g \rangle \vee (M \wedge M^{\complement}) = (\langle H,g \rangle \vee M \rangle) \wedge (\langle H,g \rangle \vee M^{\complement} \rangle)$.
 So $ \langle H,g \rangle = \langle H,a,g \rangle \wedge \langle H,g,b \rangle = G$. The result follows. $\square$

The converse of Ore's theorem is false because $\langle S_2,(1234) \rangle = S_4$ but $[S_2, S_4]$ is  not distributive.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a proper answer, but is a bit too long for a comment. You should look at the following paper:

> [*Groups and Lattices*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220813115555/http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Ewilliamdemeo/latticetheory/Palfy-GroupsAndLattices-GStA-2001.pdf) by P.P. Palfy

First, he states a stronger version of Ore's result:

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be any group. The subgroup lattice $\mathcal{L}(G)$
> is distributive if
> and only if the group
> $G$
> is locally cyclic. (i.e. every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.)

Second he states a theorem (proved by various people at various times, sometimes erroneously):

> **Theorem** If $D$ is a finite distributive lattice, then $D$ is isomorphic (as a lattice) to the lattice of normal subgroups of some finite group $G$.

Finally the result that may be of most interest to you:

> **Corollary 5.3** For every finite distributive lattice $D$, there exists a finite group $G$ such that, for $H=\{(g,g) \mid g\in G\}$, then the lattice of subgroup inclusions $\mathcal{L}(H\subset (G\times G))$ is isomorphic to $D$.

Perhaps you know all this already...

Comment: There's also Roland Schmidt's nice book "Subgroup lattices of groups", which goes into a bit more depth on most of these and many related topics.

Comment: @RussWoodroofe: yes I've transcribed the proof of the Ore's theorem from this book. Unfortunately, neither this book nor Palfy's paper answer my question.