# An optimal lower bound related to generators in a boolean interval of finite groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, computational-group-theory

Let $[H,G]$ be a rank $n$ boolean interval of finite groups (i.e. $[H,G] \simeq B_n$ as lattice).

Let the set $E = \{  g \in G \ | \ \langle H,g \rangle = G \}$
*Remark*: If $g \in E$ then $Hg \subset E$; so $|E|$ is a multiple of $|H|$.

**Question**:  $|E| / |H| \ge 2^{n-1}$?  $ \ $   [checked by GAP for $|G:H| < 32$]
(the left-hand side can be interpreted as an alternating sum of indices, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232039/34538))

*Remark*: If this lower bound is correct then it is optimal because realized by $[1 \times S_2^{n-1} , S_2 \times S_3^{n-1} ]$.

The proof of the following theorem could help to answer the question.

**Theorem**: $E \neq \emptyset $.
*proof by induction on the rank $n$*:
If $n = 1$ then $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, so $E = G - H \neq \emptyset$.
Now, we assume it is true for every rank $<n$ and we will prove it for rank $n$.
Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, and $M^{\complement}$ the lattice-complement of $M$ in $[H,G]$
(i.e. $M \vee M^{\complement} = G$ and $M \wedge M^{\complement} = H$; existence and unicity come from the boolean structure).
 By induction there are $a, b \in G$ such that $\langle H,a \rangle = M$ and $\langle H,b \rangle = M^{\complement}$. Let $g=a  b$ then $a=g  b^{-1}$ and $b=a^{-1}g$, so $\langle H,a,g \rangle = \langle H,g,b \rangle = \langle H,a,b \rangle =  M \vee M^{\complement} = G$.
 Now, $\langle H,g \rangle =  \langle H,g \rangle \vee H = \langle H,g \rangle \vee (M \wedge M^{\complement})$ but by distributivity $\langle H,g \rangle \vee (M \wedge M^{\complement}) = (\langle H,g \rangle \vee M \rangle) \wedge (\langle H,g \rangle \vee M^{\complement} \rangle)$.
 So $ \langle H,g \rangle = \langle H,a,g \rangle \wedge \langle H,g,b \rangle = G$. $\square$

*Remark*: this result is also true in the distributive case (due to O. Ore, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/195331/34538)), but it can be reduced to the boolean case (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212340/34538)) which is easier to prove as above.