# An alternative proof of a subgroup lattice characterization of the infinite cyclic group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lattice-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

In Schmidt's book *Subgroup lattices of groups*, Theorem 1.2.5 states that a group $G$ is cyclic if and only if its subgroup lattice $L(G)$ is distributive and satisfies the [maximal condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition). Its proof uses Ore's theorem stating that the subgroup lattice of a group $G$ is distributive if and only if $G$ is locally cyclic. The proof of this last requires the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups (FTFGAG).

**Question**: Is there a proof of Theorem 1.2.5 which does not use FTFGAG?
*Remark*: In the finite case, such a proof exists (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/195331/34538) with $H=1$).

*Motivation*: Carmela Musella and Maria De Falco asked me for a relative version of Theorem 1.2.5.