# Generalization of a theorem of Øystein Ore in group theory: the infinite case

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lattice-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

This post is the *infinite* version of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179555/34538), and is motivated by an exchange with [Carmela Musella](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/MRAuthorID/617290) and [Maria De Falco](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/MRAuthorID/643036). We are interested in relative versions of the following Ore's theorem and corollary. For a reference, see Section 1.2 in Schmidt's book [*Subgroup lattices of groups*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1292462).

**Theorem**: A group $G$ is [locally cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group) iff its subgroup lattice $L(G)$ is [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice).

**Corollary**: A group $G$ is cyclic iff $L(G)$ is distributive and satisfies one of the following properties:

- [maximal condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition),
- for any subgroup $K \neq 1$, the interval $[K,G]$ is finite,
- for any subgroup $K \neq 1$, the index $|G:K|$ is finite,
- for any $K,K' \in L(G)$, $|G:K| = |G:K'|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $K=K'$.

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup.
**Definitions**: the group $G$ is called *$H$-cyclic* if there is $g \in G$ such that $\langle H,g \rangle = G$.
It is called *locally $H$-cyclic* if for any finite subset $S \subset G$, the subgroup $\langle H \cup S \rangle$ is $H$-cyclic.

*Remark*: the group $G$ is $H$-cyclic iff the [hypergroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperstructure) $G/H$ is *singly generated*, as $\langle H,g \rangle = \langle Hg \rangle$.

Assume that the interval $[H,G] \subseteq L(G)$ is distributive.
**Question 1**: Is  $G$ locally $H$-cyclic?

Assume moreover that $[H,G]$ satisfies the following property ($x$), with $x \in \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$:
(1) maximal condition,
(2) for any $K \in (H,G]$, the interval $[K,G]$ is finite,
(3) for any $K \in (H,G]$, the index $|G:K|$ is finite,
(4) for any $K,K' \in [H,G]$, $|G:K| = |G:K'|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $K=K'$.

**Question 2($x$)**: $G$ is $H$-cyclic?

Note that Q1 > Q2(1) > Q2(2) > Q2(3) > Q2(4).
*Remark*: All these questions have a positive answer if the interval $[H,G]$ is finite (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/195331/34538)).

*Observation*: with (2) we have the following immediate (but promising) result: $$\forall g \in G \setminus H, \ \exists g' \in G \text{ such that } \langle H,g,g' \rangle = G \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

If $H = 1$, the property $(*)$ is known as $\frac{3}{2}$-generation (see [this poster](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~baumeist/wop2017/poster/Harper_poster.pdf) of Scott Harper, and [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/324060/34538)).
*Proposition*: If $G$ is $\frac{3}{2}$-generated then every proper quotient of $G$ is cyclic ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124888/classification-of-groups-whose-any-non-trivial-element-can-be-associate-to-anoth#comment6438252_3124888)).
*Conjecture* (Breuer-Guralnick-Kantor): A finite group is  $\frac{3}{2}$-generated iff every proper quotient is cyclic.
*Theorem* (Guralnick-Kantor): Every finite simple group is $\frac{3}{2}$-generated.

If $G$ satisfies $(*)$, the hypergroup $G/H$ can be called $\frac{3}{2}$-generated, as $\langle H,g,g' \rangle = \langle Hg, Hg' \rangle$.