# Breuer-Guralnick-Kantor conjecture and infinite 3/2-generated groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

A group $G$ is called $\frac{3}{2}$-generated if every non-trivial element is contained in a generating pair, i.e. $$\forall g \in G \setminus \{e \}, \ \exists g' \in G \text{ such that } \langle g,g' \rangle = G.$$

See this [nice poster](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~baumeist/wop2017/poster/Harper_poster.pdf) of Scott Harper.
*Proposition*: If $G$ is $\frac{3}{2}$-generated then every proper quotient of $G$ is cyclic ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124888/classification-of-groups-whose-any-non-trivial-element-can-be-associate-to-anoth#comment6438252_3124888)).
*Conjecture* (B.G.K.): A finite group is  $\frac{3}{2}$-generated iff every proper quotient is cyclic.
*Theorem* (G.K.): Every finite simple group is $\frac{3}{2}$-generated.

**Question**: Can the above conjecture be extended to $2$-generated groups?
 In other words: Is there a (known) counter-example for such groups?
In particular: Is every $2$-generated infinite simple group $\frac{3}{2}$-generated?

*Examples*: the [Tarski monster groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) are infinite simple and $\frac{3}{2}$-generated.

Obviously, any infinite simple group which is not $2$-generated (like the infinite alternating group $A_{\infty}$ which is not finitely generated) has every proper quotient cyclic, but is not $\frac{3}{2}$-generated.

*Bonus question*: Is there a finitely generated simple group which is not $2$-generated?

There are these notions of [*strictly simple group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_simple_group) and [*absolutely simple group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_simple_group) which are equivalent to *simple group* in the finite case, but are stronger in the infinite case (the second being even stronger than the first). It could be relevant to consider the questions as above for these stronger notions.

Comment: An example answering the bonus question was given by Guba: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00969195?LI=true

Comment: To be clear, the article @JeremyRickard [links](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324060/breuer-guralnick-kantor-conjecture-and-infinite-3-2-generated-groups#comment808648_324060) answers the bonus question ("Is there a finitely generated simple group which is not 2-generated?") positively.

Comment: Guba's paper: here's the reference: *V. Guba, A finitely generated simple group with free 2-generated subgroups Siberian Math. J. 27(5) (1986), 670-684*. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00969195

Comment: I would tend to believe that the kind of method (of small cancelation type) used could be adapted to also obtain counterexamples for the other question, e.g. by constructing a simple group generated by $\{x,y\}$, such that, say, $\{x^2,z\}$ generates a free subgroup for every $z$.