# Infinite group generated by a single coset

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lattice-theory, infinite-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $G$ be an infinite countable group having a core-free subgroup $H$ such that the interval $[H,G]$ in the subgroup lattice $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is [ACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) of infinite length, and for every $K \in (H,G]$, $G$ is generated by a single $K$-coset (i.e. there is $g \in G$ with $\langle Kg \rangle = G$).

**Question**: Is $G$ generated by a single $H$-coset?

It is an exercise to reformulate as:  let $[H,G]$ be an ACC interval of groups and $(K_i)_{i \in I}$ its [coatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(order_theory)#Coatoms), i.e. the maximal elements in $[H,G)$. Assume that  $I$ is an infinite countable set, and for every *finite* subset $J \subset I$ we have $\bigcap_{j \in J} (G \setminus K_j) \neq \emptyset.$   *Question*: Is it true that $\bigcap_{i \in I} (G \setminus K_i) \neq \emptyset$?

*Examples*: for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \{0\}$, the ACC is satisfied, the coatoms are $(p\mathbb{Z})_{p \in \mathbb{P}}$ and $\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{P}} (\mathbb{Z} \setminus p\mathbb{Z}) = \{-1,1 \} \neq \emptyset$. For $G = \mathbb{Z} \rtimes C_2$ and $H = C_2$, it works as well.
Any other example (with $H$ core-free) is welcome!

**Application**: [Generalization of a theorem of Øystein Ore in group theory: the infinite case](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323887/34538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no". Let $G$ be a Tarski torsion-free monster,  $H$ be the trivial subgroup. Then $(H,G]$ consists of $G$ and all cyclic subgroups of $G$, it has ACC and infinite length. If $K$ is a cyclic subgroup and $a$ is not in the cyclic centralizer $C(K)$, then the coset $aK$ contains two non-commuting elements, so it generates $G$ but no coset of $H$ generates $G$.

Comment: @Sebastien Palcoux: Olshanskiy ''s book "Geometry of defining relations" or use Google.

Comment: I got the expected result in Ol'shanskii's book: Theorem 28.3 (on page 306): "There is a simple torsion-free group $G$ (...) in which every proper subgroup is infinite cyclic (...) any two maximal subgroups in $G$ have trivial intersection". Then on page 307 he wrote: "The lattice of subgroups of $G$ has a very simple structure: it consists of a countable number of lattices of subgroups of an infinite cyclic group pasted together at the trivial subgroup and the whole group $G$."

Comment: By the way, Mark implicitly means "torsion-free". Indeed, there exist infinite 2-generated groups in which every proper subgroup is finite cyclic, and which have infinite exponent (they are actually easier to produce than their better known finite exponent cousins — and the torsion-free ones are also easier).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Your Google is damaged.       https://www.google.com/search?q=torsion-free+Tarski+monster&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS865US865&oq=torsion-free&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.7269j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8